# Show only 32 results in C#

Tags: c#

**Problem: I have a method that is more the 32 results.**

I have tried the following:

```
<%
int i1; 
string desc = "";
for (i1 = 1; i1 <= 32; i1++){
    if ("PCDDC" + i1.ToString() != "") {
        desc += "<BR>" + "PCDDC_Description" + i1.ToString();
        Response.Write(desc.Remove(0,6));
    }
}
%>
```

I am getting over 32 results when I display the string. I am not sure why.

Comment: `"PCDDC" + i1.ToString() != ""` this will always be true...  5 + anything != 0

Comment: @MrZander: It still displays more then 32 results. And yes I have removed that statement and it still displays over 32 results

Comment: I was just pointing out the useless if statement.

Comment: @MrZander Okay. Still not sure why it goes over the count

Comment: move ```Response.Write(desc.Remove(0,6)); ``` till after your for loop

Answer (score 4):

You're concatenating your desired output to a temporary variable then outputting that.

Change it from `desc += "<BR...` to `desc = "<BR...`.

Other issues:

- Your `i1` variable has no use outside of the `for` loop, so move the declaration inline: `for(int i1 = 1; i1 <= 32; i1++) {`
- `"<BR>"` is not keeping with present-day HTML convention. We use lowercase tags, and use `<br />` if you want compatibility with XHTML and XML.
- As others have pointed out, your `if` statement's expression will always evaluate to `false`.
- `String` mutation operations (concatenation, `Substring`, `Remove`, etc) are generally expensive (as they involved the allocation of a new string) and should be avoided in high-performance code. In your case the call to `desc.Remove(0,6)` is unnecessary because you can output the string directly.
- It looks like you're writing HTML inside a render function block (the `<% %>`). Your code might be easier to read if you keep all HTML as literals instead, like so:

  ```
  <% for(int i = 1; i <= 32; i++) { %>
  PCDC_Description<%: i %><br />
  <% } %>
  ```
- Assuming you're using ASP.NET 4.0 or later, you should use `<%:` instead of `<%=` or `<% Response.Write(` because it automatically performs HTML-encoding of strings, this is essential to avoid a variety of injection attacks such as XSS.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's look at the output you pasted in before it got edited out (with a little formatting on my part):

```
86644
86644, 86645
86644, 86645, 86664
86644, 86645, 86664, 86663
86644, 86645, 86664, 86663, 86777
```

Are you seeing a pattern? You're adding one and then printing the whole thing over again.

With that in mind, let's also look at the code:

```
if ("PCDDC" + i1.ToString() != "") {
```

This `if` statement will ALWAYS be `true`.

```
desc += "<BR>" + "PCDDC_Description" + i1.ToString();
```

You're tacking `i1.ToString()` onto a string literal. This doesn't jive with the output you pasted in to begin with but it does show that you're adding your output onto this single `desc` variable. This means 2 things: Don't print your output inside your loop as well, and you aren't using `StringBuilder` when you should be.

```
Response.Write(desc.Remove(0,6));
```

And then you're outputting your string inside your `for` loop after modifying it for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you always append to desc, and print it in every iteration. This results in the first item printed 32 times, like in this pattern: `1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 etc...`. Just replace `desc +=` with `desc =` and this problem will go away.

Most of the code will still be nonsense though. For example: `if ("PCDDC1" != "")` will always be true and so enter the block.